# $ rails g pundit:install errors 'const_get' : wrong constant name Admin? (Name Error) while attempting to generate default policy library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, pundit

New to ROR working through a tutorial attempting to generate a default policy file for my application with the `pundit:install`.

`$ rails g pundit:install` generates the following error:

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/models.rb:88:in `const_get': wrong constant name Admin? (NameError)
```

I also tried captilizing pundit with the following command:
`$ rails g Pundit:install` , but it generates the same error:

Comment: Have you installed the gem, does `which pundit` return a path?

Comment: Yes, I installed the gem in the Gemfile and ran bundle install. But it will not install on rails with: $rails g pundit:install

Comment: `which pundit ` does not return a path

Comment: I don't think the pundit gem installs an executable. If that's the case, then its correct that `which pundit` does not return a path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given error message doesn't yet point to Pundit as being the problem:

`` .rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/models.rb:88:
in `const_get': wrong constant name Admin? (NameError) ``

Is there a longer stack trace for the error message? If yes, please add it to the question.

Also search your app's files for `Admin?` (with a capital 'A'). See that `Admin?` is mentioned in the error message `wrong constant name Admin?`.

(At a guess, somewhere in the app, `Admin?` is written where it should not be. Perhaps it needs to be removed or replaced with small 'a': `admin?`. Or replaced with `Admin` without the question mark.)

Comment: Great Help. I had a "Has Registered?" column name which was causing error with devise